# shiny-server no plot in example app?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Hello I am trying to setup a shiny server and I noticed on the example `sample-apps/hello/` app that there is no plot being drawn. I see the `It's Alive!` message and the `Number of bins` slider but I do not see any plot or graph. Can anyone tell me why?

I am using R version 3.2.0 and shiny-server-1.5.3.838.

```
> library(shiny); sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.11.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] R6_2.0.1        htmltools_0.2.6 Rcpp_0.11.6     RJSONIO_1.3-0
[5] digest_0.6.6    xtable_1.7-4    httpuv_1.3.2    mime_0.3
```

I also see this js error every time I move the slider. Not sure if it's relevant.
`Uncaught Error: Invalid robust-message, no msg-id found`

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that plots random distributions
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  # Application title
  headerPanel("It's Alive!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of observations
  sidebarPanel(
    sliderInput("bins",
                  "Number of bins:",
                  min = 1,
                  max = 50,
                  value = 30)
  ),

  # Show a plot of the generated distribution
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("distPlot", height=250)
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Expression that generates a histogram. The expression is
  # wrapped in a call to renderPlot to indicate that:
  #
  #  1) It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
  #     re-executed when inputs change
  #  2) Its output type is a plot

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2]  # Old Faithful Geyser data
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })

})
```

Comment: shiny itself is updated quite a bit recently, so I'd start with updating your R to the latest version, then update all packages in R and try again.

Comment: @Joris Meys Yeah you're right it's a version compatibility issue. Unfortunately I can't update R or its packages, but I did downgrade shiny-server to 1.4 and I can see the plot now.

Comment: Nice to know your problem is temporarily solved. Keep in mind though that more and more packages will require newer versions of R to be installed. Especially everything related to the tidyverse might cause serious conflicts. So I still would advise you to get R updated one way or another as soon as possible. If you need older versions of R for legacy code, you can keep the old installation or take a look at `packrat`.